# Error: There are no 'Deprecated_Private_NAT' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: Public

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc, subnet

Why am I getting this error when the subnet type that I'm trying to call is `PRIVATE_WITH_NAT`?

```py
vpc_subnets = aws_ec2.SubnetSelection(
    subnets=vpc.select_subnets(subnet_type=aws_ec2.SubnetType(aws_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT)).subnets
),
```

Error `Error: There are no 'Deprecated_Private_NAT' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: Public`

I tried to print the value of subnet type, but no deprecated_private_NAT.

```py
print([t.value for t in aws_ec2.SubnetType])
['PRIVATE_ISOLATED', 'PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS', 'PRIVATE_WITH_NAT', 'PUBLIC']
```

Answer (score 2):

In the CDK's (Typescript) [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/0b822b36bc2bb8d786d9c2fb7c8f493d80564384/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-ec2/lib/vpc.ts#L227), the string value of the `SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT` enum is `Deprecated_Private_NAT`.  I don't know how jsii converts this to Python.

In any case, `PRIVATE_WITH_NAT` is deprecated.  Use `PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS` instead.

Note, though, that the error message suggests your VPC only has Public subnets available.